# Reguar Expression to fetch single line and multi line from python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

Input Data

```
I am not Myc wooo0
Myc wooo1
Myc wooo3
+ rt ...4
do not consider me5
Myc wooo6
+ rt ....7
+ rt ....8
do not consider me9
+ rt ....10
+ rt ....11
Myc wooo12
```

I have the above input data, need to fetch line with following conditions -

1. line must start with "Myc"
2. line must start with "Myc" and followed line must start with "+ "

Expected Output:

```
Myc wooo -1 I am fist
Myc wooo1
Myc wooo3
+ rt ...4
Myc wooo6
+ rt ....7
Myc wooo12
```

I try with following reguar expression in Python.

```
    pattern_myc = '\n(Myc[^\n]*\n\+[^\n]*\n|Myc[^\n]*\n)'
    result_lines = re.findall(pattern_myc, input_text)
```

but not getting the expected output.

I tried with the string process, I was able to get the expected output.

Due to large data, I want to work with regular experssion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in MULTILINE mode:

```bash
^Myc.*(?:\r?\n\+.*)?
```

or this with inline MULTILINE mode:

```bash
(?m)^Myc.*(?:\r?\n\+.*)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQWTzb/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^Myc`: Match `Myc` at the start
- `.*`: Match any text
- `(?:\r?\n\+.*)?`: Optionally match a new line followed by `+` and everything in that second line

**Code:**

```bash
import re

result_lines = re.findall(r"(?m)^Myc.*(?:\r?\n\+.*)?", input_text)
print (result_lines)
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I tried in python code but its give only  ` ['Myc wooo -1 I am fist1']` line. I am using  `result_lines = re.findall(r"^Myc.*(?:\r?\n\+.*)?", input_text)`

Comment: As I wrote you need to use MULTILINE mode. Use it like this: `re.findall(r"(?m)^Myc.*(?:\r?\n\+.*)?", input_text)`

Comment: Thank you, I added  \n in regex to consider new line characters because need to wirte this lines into file. `r"(?m)^Myc.*(?:\r?\n\+.*)?\n"`